# CategoryAttribute in c++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I read code and fuond the word `CategoryAttribute`.

What is a CategoryAttribute in c++/cli?

Comment: Via Google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx

Comment: The msdn isn't clear.  Tha's why I asked.  I can find msdn myself.  Don't need help in googling..

Answer (score 0):

While I think it's clear, I have a few seconds to answer.

It's a CLR attribute class (a modifier available through reflection) that specifies which category/grouping the property should be listed under in a property grid view.  Like when you're editing a form, the thing that you change values in like Text, Size, Docking, etc.